# JWT jsonwebtoken dosen't expired in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I'm using `"jsonwebtoken": "^5.4.0"`, I'am not able to expire my token

I create the token with:

```
var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
    expiresInSeconds: 1
});
```

My token is like

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NjFhODE5MjFhZGJmYWI2MzNlZWU4ZjciLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImJhcm5vIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiIkMmEkMTAkcnh6SHY0dFFhbkxwVDNQOEVJSzNBTzVhLjcwNUJZdmxIOVhXOHlSVmpUMi9hNEdmTFd4YU8iLCJfX3YiOjAsImNyZWF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDE1LTEwLTExVDE1OjM0OjQyLjg3MFoifQ.ooELWBRlxtYwFTmJDFNOLiR6-2uR_-wjjXwPnS0c5Lk
```

In my middleware I have this check

```
jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'});
    } else {
        console.dir(decoded);            
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        req.decoded = decoded;
        return res.json({success: true, token: decoded});
        next();
    }
});
```

With Postman I do a Post Request Like

```
Post http://localhost:3000/users
with
x-access-token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NjFhODE5MjFhZGJmYWI2MzNlZWU4ZjciLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImJhcm5vIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiIkMmEkMTAkcnh6SHY0dFFhbkxwVDNQOEVJSzNBTzVhLjcwNUJZdmxIOVhXOHlSVmpUMi9hNEdmTFd4YU8iLCJfX3YiOjAsImNyZWF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDE1LTEwLTExVDE1OjM0OjQyLjg3MFoifQ.ooELWBRlxtYwFTmJDFNOLiR6-2uR_-wjjXwPnS0c5Lk
```

And My token is always valid!

```
console.dir(decoded)
{
  "success": true,
  "token": {
    "_id": "561a81921adbfab633eee8f7",
    "username": "myuser",
  }
}
```

Why my code is always valid? How can I force to invalidate this code, for example like logout?

Comment: looking at the payload using the debugger at jwt.io, your token does not contain the ´exp´ field

Comment: Force invalid through changing the expiry time to current time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

library might not invalidate token by time itself. In your case signature might be correct, so you get **decoded** variable. Probably you need to check it yourself.

Here is very useful tool to check what JWT token you actually generated. 
http://jwt.io/#debugger

Answer (score 0):

When using jwt.sign(), the first argument provided must be an object. Try replacing your code as below.

```
var token = jwt.sign({user: user}, app.get('superSecret'), {
    expiresIn: 1
});
```

Also, use expiresIn instead of expiresInSeconds as it has been deprecated.